# Where does the default Earth radius in ST_Distance_Sphere come from?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mysql, mysql-spatial

MySQL says in the docs for [`ST_Distance_Sphere`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html)

> Calculations use a spherical earth and a configurable radius. The optional radius argument should be given in meters. If omitted, the **default radius is 6,370,986 meters.** If the radius argument is present but not positive, an `ER_WRONG_ARGUMENTS` error occurs.

[PostGIS](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.4/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html) says in the docs of [`ST_Distance_Sphere`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.4/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html), (though [the docs aren't accurate anymore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/191277/2639))

> Uses a spherical earth and radius of 6370986 meters.

**Where did they get the default 6,370,986 meters from?** [WGS84](https://epsg.io/4326) says major-axis radius is 6,378,137.0 m. PostGIS which now uses a Average Radius essentially uses 6371008.

Looking [at the code](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/f7c5af893bb99e33db23d513500d6b66f7dbf0ce/liblwgeom/liblwgeom.h.in#L127)

```
#define WGS84_MAJOR_AXIS 6378137.0
#define WGS84_INVERSE_FLATTENING 298.257223563
#define WGS84_MINOR_AXIS (WGS84_MAJOR_AXIS - WGS84_MAJOR_AXIS / WGS84_INVERSE_FLATTENING)
#define WGS84_RADIUS ((2.0 * WGS84_MAJOR_AXIS + WGS84_MINOR_AXIS ) / 3.0)
```

that means

```
-- SELECT 6378137.0 - 6378137.0 / 298.257223563;
WGS84_MINOR_AXIS = 6356752.314245179498
-- SELECT ( 2.0 * 6378137.0 + ( 6378137.0 - 6378137.0 / 298.257223563) ) / 3.0;
WGS84_RADIUS = 6371008.771415059833
```

Newer versions are much less efficient, more complex, and use Pro4j but they seem to do the same thing.

**Still where does 6370986 come from?**

Comment: It represents the mean earth radius, which [should be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius#Mean_radius) `(2*minorAxis+majorAxis)/3` ... though that value for WGS84 is still a few meters larger (6,371,008.771)

Comment: yep, that's the question why the discrepancy.

Comment: Some developer looked it up on the net? The postgis source may throw some light on it

Comment: @IanTurton Most bugs can be reduced to "some developer did something and the source may throw light on it." I intended to do the work, figuring that would be what it takes if no one knew the story. See the answer below.

Comment: Maybe there was a typo and they meant 6370996...that's very close to Clarke 1866's authalic radius.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok, this is *hilarriuusss*. I tracked this down. In an old copy of [`lwgeom/lwgeom_spheroid.c` in PostGIS 1.0.0rc4](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/commit/d1e58a9a5b403fb6fb7ccd2bd073305fad446ce8#diff-30a67e468380a27a703a608570ca9703R538) you can see this,

```
/*
 * This algorithm was taken from the geo_distance function of the 
 * earthdistance package contributed by Bruno Wolff III.
 * It was altered to accept GEOMETRY objects and return results in
 * meters.
 */
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(LWGEOM_distance_sphere);
Datum LWGEOM_distance_sphere(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
        const double EARTH_RADIUS = 6370986.884258304;
```

Moving on to the docs of [`earthdistance`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/earthdistance.html#idm46428636109744), you'll find this:

> Note that unlike the cube-based part of the module, units are hardwired here: changing the `earth()` function will not affect the results of this operator.

And that hard-wired number: [`EARTH_RADIUS` can be seen here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/55c3391d1e6a201b5b891781d21fe682a8c64fe6/contrib/earthdistance/earthdistance.c#L16)

```
/* Earth's radius is in statute miles. */
static const double EARTH_RADIUS = 3958.747716;
```

So you can do a simple.

```
EARTH_RADIUS * MILES_TO_METERS = EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS
 3958.747716 * 1609.344        = 6370986.884258304
```

And you have your `6370986.884258304`. Of course, just truncate that and store it in a `long` because why not.

So in essence, the radius in MySQL was [lifted from a lazy-copy-job from PostGIS](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/commit/09a1a705ad35878eac022b086bccfe5eaeb7e5ed#diff-69b470033f1a3104f3a82cd9c3eed31cR9259) that [converted a radius in miles to meters](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/commit/d1e58a9a5b403fb6fb7ccd2bd073305fad446ce8#diff-30a67e468380a27a703a608570ca9703R538) from an obscure constant from a [random 20-year old PostgreSQL module](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/5815523b0e9731da9355dfcc6899829a21314855/contrib/earthdistance/earthdistance.c#L10).

`earth_distance` is a pre-PostGIS module by Bruce Momjian. I hereby proclaim 6370986 the Bmomjian Constant: a good nuff' approximation of Earth in meters to satisfy MySQL. Though [maybe not for long.](https://twitter.com/mattalord/status/933321969923166208)

Comment: But where did that very precise figure 3958.747716 come from, then? The closest I can find is 3958.74795, which is the number of U.S. _survey_ miles in 6371 kilometers, but that still leaves about 37 cm unaccounted for ,,,

Comment: @HenningMakholm keep fighting the good fight no idea. ;)

Comment: Very nice find!